# Check the convergence of $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( (-1)^{n} (\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n-1})\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to check the convergence of this series:
$$\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( (-1)^{n} (\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n-1})\right)$$
I tried to multiply it by its compliment but no result.( I`m cheking it on the positive series )
I would like to get some advice how to do that.Thanks!

Comment: Is the entire thing supposed to be multiplied by $(-1)^n$, or just the first square root?

Comment: I`m doing it on the positive series..

Comment: Hint: The square roots of odd integers cancel out, so you can get rid of the $(-1)^n$.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question: is the $n$th summand supposed to be $$(-1)^n\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n-1},$$ as written, or rather the following?
$$(-1)^n(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n-1})$$

Comment: I do not think you got the right summand.

Comment: fixed that as in the header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Use alternating series test and

$$  (\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n-1})\times  \frac{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n-1}}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n-1}}$$

$$ = \frac{2}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n-1}} \sim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} $$

Comment: I did that and got finally : $\frac{2}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n-1}}$

Comment: @OfirAttia What do you know about the convergence of alternating series?

Comment: ok, got it.. I chose $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$ but now all clear!

Comment: @OfirAttia: Good.

Comment: And the value of the sum is $____$.

Answer (score 0):

Another hint: $\sqrt{1+1/n} = 1+\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{8n^2}+\mathcal O(n^{-3})$.